# how to unwrap a std::reference_wrapper like boost::unwrap_reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I am tring to port some code, that uses boost::unwrap_reference a lot to C++11. The code calls a lot member functions, like

```
template< typename T, typename Y>
void initialize( T _t, Y y)
{

    typename boost::unwrap_reference< T >::type & t = _t;

    t.doSomethingNastyWithY( y );
}   

// The function is called like this
struct DoSomething
{
     template<typename Y>
     void doSomethingNastyWithY(Y y)
     {
         // do stuff
     }
};

struct Object {};

DoSomething s;
Object obj;

int main()
{
    initialize( s, obj ); // Take a copy of DoSomething
    initialize( boost::ref(s), obj ); // Uses DoSomething as reference
}
```

I couldn't find an equivalent to boost::unwrap_reference in the STL, is there an other straight forward way to do this?

EDIT: I clarified the example a bit

Comment: and the `_t_stepper` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
template< typename T >
struct UnwrapReference;

template< typename T >
struct UnwrapReference { typedef T type; }

template< >
struct UnwrapReference< std::reference_wrapper< T > > { typedef T type; }
```

Untested though, but that's the gist of how you'd probably be able to do it.

Comment: Thx, by adding the following code it also works when used with boost::ref instead of std::ref  
   
    namespace boost {

    template<typename T> class reference_wrapper;
    template<typename T> class unwrap_reference;
    
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct UnwrapReference< boost::reference_wrapper<T> >
    {
            typedef typename boost::unwrap_reference<T>::type type;
    };