# How to avoid writing std::reference_wrapper version template all the time?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a function template to echo something from the class, for example:

```
template<typename T>
void say(const std::vector<T>& ts)
{
    for (const auto& t : ts) {
        std::cout<<t.getDesc()<<std::endl;
    }
}

class Base
{
public
    Base();
    const std::string& getDesc() const {
        return m_desc;
    }
protected:
    std::string m_desc;
}
```

All objects inherited from `Base` can use the template function.

```
std::vector<Base> v;
Base a;
v.push_back(a)
```

But when I turn to `std::reference_wrapper`, the function template does not work. I should write another template to fix it.

```
template<typename T>
void say(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>& ts)
{
    for (const auto& t : ts) {
        std::cout<<t.get().getDesc()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The only difference between them is the `std::reference_wrapper::get()`.

So is there any other way to avoid this annoying code? Or should I write std::reference_wrapper version template for all the function I used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite the whole thing. Just use a level of indirection.

```
namespace detail {
  template<typename T>
  constexpr T& get(T &t) { return t; }

  template<typename T>
  constexpr T const& get(T const &t) { return t; }

  template<typename T>
  constexpr T& get(std::reference_wrapper<T> rt) { return rt; }
}

template<typename T>
void say(const std::vector<T>& ts)
{
    for (const auto& t : ts) {
        std::cout<< detail::get(t) <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above functions in the `detail` namespace are reusable of course (though could be better named), and can make all your templates work with `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Is that const-correct? I mean `get(rw)` with rw of type `reference_wrapper<T> const&` should really return `T&`, not `T const&`

Comment: @sehe - Figures I'd make a mistake like this. You are right. Amended the answer.

Comment: The [edit is a bit weird though](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85f6e7f2b81c790b). My suggestion: [simpler is better](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80ce0f5a66b0942d)

Comment: @sehe - It's funny, but I wrote a long winded diatribe today about why value semantics would be better in a case such as this. Thanks for making me follow my own advice :)

Comment: Yeah! I just went the extra mile to verify that compilers do make the best of it: https://godbolt.org/g/ztWgz2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper `Unwrap` template such as `boost::unwrap_reference`. Or write your own, copying the code from this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9972636/865874):

```
template< typename T >
struct UnwrapReference;

template< typename T >
struct UnwrapReference { typedef T type; }

template< >
struct UnwrapReference< std::reference_wrapper< T > > { typedef T type; }
```

Now you can write one version of your function to bind them all (untested):

```
template<typename T>
void say(const std::vector<T>& ts)
{
    for (const UnwrapReference<T>::type &t : ts) {
        std::cout<<t.getDesc()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```